# corrupted .docx document after downloading asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to export a aspx page with image in it into a word document. When I try to achieve this with .doc format then broken image appears on the word doc. I tried downloading it in .docx format but after modifying code for .docx, it give me file corrupted error while opening. Below is my code:

```
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <asp:Panel ID="tblReport" runat="server">
          <div class="boxed1a">
                    <img class="images4" src="Images/Penguins.jpg" width="640" height="45" />
                    <table class="tb3">
                    <tr>
                    <td>Leasehold & Functional Programs</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>N/A</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Acquis Maint & Renov</td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
    </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExport" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
        </form>
    </body>



    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=report.docx");

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                tblReport.RenderControl(htw);
                Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

Please let me know how can achieve this with .docx format.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Text writer is not a right way to create Word document in .net.

You could use the following code to create a simple word document and take reference from the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx.

The above link will help you to create an efficient word document in .net.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application objWord;
 object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
 FolderBrowserDialog ff = new FolderBrowserDialog();
 ff.ShowDialog();
 string filename = "Sample";
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objDoc;
 objWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 objWord.Visible = true;
 objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
 wrdRng.Text = "Simple Word";
 this.Close();
 string fp = ff.SelectedPath + "\\" + filename + ".docx";
 objDoc.SaveAs2(fp);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interops are not designed to be used on a server. They will cause a ton of problems. However, you are on the right track.